# Run GIMP Python script from command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line, gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to run a GIMP script that I had working on a Mac earlier in the year. Only now I'm on a PC, and I can't seem to get it to run.

Originally, on the Mac I processed a folder of images with:

```
/Applications/Gimp-2.10.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp -idfs --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import myscript;myscript.run('./images')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

So, on the Win 7 PC, using the same `myscript.py` script I try to run it with the command prompt from `images` folder:

```
cd %~dp0
"D:\GIMP2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe" -idfs --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import myscript;myscript.run('./images')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

Only I get the error:

`batch command experienced an execution error gimp_check_updates_callback: loading of https://www.gimp.org/gimp_versions.json failed: GET request failed: WinHttp error: SECURE_FAILURE (Type any character to close this window)`

So I'm none the wiser for knowing where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with Gimp update mechanism: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Scripts-don-t-work-anymore-with-Gimp-2-10-20

Comment: @viilpe I've reverted to 2.10.18 but now the error is just `batch command experienced an execution error` - not so helpful :(